# Show that $\frac 1{\log_2x}+\frac 1{\log_3x}+\cdots+\frac 1{\log_{43}x}=\frac 1{\log_{43!}x}$

Tags: logarithms

Show that $\frac 1{\log_2x}+\frac 1{\log_3x}+\cdots+\frac 1{\log_{43}x}=\frac 1{\log_{43!}x}$.I am just not able to get it.please help.

Comment: Can you express $\log_b x$ in terms of the natural logarithm? That would help a lot.

Comment: @DanielFischer Is the question not possible without natural logarithm?

Comment: Can you show that $(\log_ab)(\log_ba)=1$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes i can

Comment: I suppose you could do it with the logarithm of any base (take $2$ for example)

Comment: You could also use the logarithm to the base $123456$, $37$, or $10$ as a unifying thing. But the trick is to express everything in the same base.

Comment: Then do you see how to use that formula to answer the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hints** $$\log_b x =  \frac{\log x}{\log b} \qquad \log xy = \log x + \log y$$